# How to convert string to xml

Tags: java, xml

I have a string which contains XML data and I want to convert it to XML document object. How do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

say theString holds the XML,

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(theString)));
```

More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html)

Comment: I am using this ..but when I am debugging the code ..debugger doesn't identify code after the Document doc = docBuilder.parse(theString) line.

Comment: `docBuilder.parse(theString);` expects the URI, not the string itself

Comment: In my case the doc is null. Does not work for me. I validated my xml is valid

Comment: @AnujAcharya - this answer is nearly 4 years old. It's quite likely that the technology has changed.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is pass the string to the LoadXml method of the
XmlDocument class. Then, you can use XPath to get the values of the
elements/attributes in the document.

Answer (score 0):

You could use several libraries to do this.

If you have a schema file for the XML you could use [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/) to do this. If you have no schema file you better stick with libraries like [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) or [SAXON](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/).